# How to filter current url using php

Tags: php, url

Example current URL `http://www.domain.com/subdomain/install/finish.php`

I use this code to get the current URL.

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Now I want to get the URL looks like `http://www.domain.com/subdomain` if there don't have sub-folder it will read like `http://www.domain.com`

Let me know.

Comment: URL definition can be shortened to : `$url = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://": "http://" ) . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your requirement, but take a look at [`parse_url()`](http://de.php.net/parse_url).

It splits a URL into the following fragments:

```
* scheme - http://
* host www.domain.com
* port 
* user
* pass
* path /subdomain/install/finish.php
* query  
* fragment
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this, but i've got no more votes today :( good answer!